# Is it possible to get data from Firebase that can map to multiple child classes in Java?

Tags: java, firebase, polymorphism

If I have a base class Base like this:

```
public Base
{
    private String mVar1, mVar2;

    public String getVar1(){
        return mVar1;
    }

    public void setVar1(String var1){
        mVar1 = var1;
    }

    public String getVar2(){
        return mVar2;
    }

    public void setVar2(String var2){
        mVar2 = var2;
    }
}
```

A child class called ChildA:

```
public ChildA extends Base
{
    private int mVal;

    public int getVal(){
        return mVal;
    }

    public void setVal(int val){
        mVal = val;
    }
}
```

And another child class called ChildB:

```
public ChildB extends Base
{
    private boolean mIsComplete;

    public boolean isComplete(){
        return isComplete;
    }

    public void setComplete(boolean complete){
        mIsComplete = complete;
    }
}
```

Then how can I do something like this if the child node "someKey" holds data containing ChildA and ChildB objects:

```
public static void getData(DatabaseReference dbRef)
{
    final List<Base> list = new ArrayList<>();
    dbRef.child("someKey").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                list.add(snapshot.getValue(Base.class));
            }

            //do something with the list...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

In the dataSnapshot for loop, I've tried what I have there but some of the data is not retrieved since the `Base` class does not have getters and setters for the `ChildA` and `ChildB` fields (which it should not have since those methods only apply to the child classes, not the base class).

My other option is I have to check which class each object in `snapshot` belongs to first and then pass the appropriate `<classname>.class` into `setValue(<classname>.class)` using `if/else if` statements. With that being said, is there a better way to get data that maps to multiple child classes without using a series of `if/else if` statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can override setter and getter methods in child object by calling the super's method and everything will work but it is not the best solution. 
Like:

```
@Override
public void setVar1(String var1){
    super.setVar1(var1);
}
```